# How to Convert Each Character in a String using Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a sequence of characters that I want to convert them into specified charter.

```
Seq = "AA" #This the sequence of characters

def complement (Seq):
    for nuc in Seq: # converting the sequence of characters into the desirable character 
        if nuc == 'A':
           comp = 'T'
    return comp

print "The complement of the Sequence AA is", complement(Seq)
```

When I tried to run the code above, the code is not recognizing the whole sequence of characters and convert them at a time into "T"s; however, it is only executing "T" once for the input sequence "AA"

Any idea how to make the code converts each "A" character in the sequence into "T"?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: want you find the reverse complement or reverse only of a DNA sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it is going to be only `T`. Because your loop is just appending `T` to `comp` instead of concatenating.

Try this:

```
Seq = "AA" #This the sequence of characters

def complement (Seq):
    comp = ""    <- declare empty string first
    for nuc in Seq:
        if nuc == 'A':
            comp += 'T'   <-- notice the +
    return comp

print "The complement of the Sequence AA is", complement(Seq)
```

[Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) is an basic tutorial for string concatenation and formatting.

Comment: This is working great! thank you for your help.  But could you explain what actually the + sign does? I mean function it has?

Comment: @Bahrani I am not sure what do you mean by what function it has. `+` is used to concatenate string. Lets say you have a variable `a = 'stack'` and you want your final string to be `stackoverflow`, you can concatenate using `+` sign --> `b = a + 'overflow'`

Answer (score 2):

Your script have a few errors.  First, the variable comp doesn't have a initial value and returns only one "T"(last one) because the other get replaced every time they find a "A" in the loop. For what I understand you are trying to substitute some values in the same string.  I find it easier to build a new string with the characters you want to replace.

Here is my script:

```
Seq = "AA" #This the sequence of characters

def complement (Seq):
    comp = ''
    for nuc in Seq: # converting the sequence of characters into the desirable character 
         if nuc == 'A':
             comp += 'T'
         else:
             comp += nuc
    return comp

print "The complement of the Sequence AA is", complement(Seq)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `string.maketrans` to build a translation table. That function takes two strings, and builds a table that maps each character of the first string to the corresponding character in the second string. Now, you can pass that table to the `translate` method of the string you want to translate.

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans("ATCG", "TAGC")
>>> 'AAAGTC'.translate(table)
'TTTCAG'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of that after the condition you just put the `'T'` on `comp` and at last returned it:

```
    if nuc == 'A':
       comp = 'T'
return comp
```

But as a more pythonic way you can use `str.replace()` :

```
>>> Seq = "AA"
>>> Seq.replace('A','T')
'TT'
```

And if you want to convert each character to a special character based on a condition you can use a list comprehension and `join` :

```
>>> Seq = "AA"
>>> ''.join(['T' for i in Seq if i=='A'])
'TT'
```

Also based on your task you can have another choices like using regex.Which in that case python comes with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function to replace a string based on a regex.

Comment: I want to learn it the hard way using the for loop.  How could we tweak it?

Comment: @Bahrani Who has said the hard way is good always? In programming world always the winner is the much optimized way (in terms of memory use or execution speed). Anyway the list comprehension approach use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

if, you want get complement of sequence of DNA

```
complement = {"A":"T", "C":"G", "G":"C", "T":"A"}
seq = "ACGT"
complement_seq = "".join([complement[b] for b in seq])
complement_seq
```

this is similar to,

```
complement = {"A":"T", "C":"G", "G":"C", "T":"A"}
seq = "ACGT"
complement_seq = ""
for base in seq:
  complement_seq += complement[base]

complement_seq
```

you get

```
TGCA
```

better, using biopython library

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq = Seq("ACGT")
my_seq.complement()
```

you get

```
Seq('TGCA', Alphabet())
```

Comment: How can we do it using a for loop? any idea?